# How to use Mean squared error as the loss function on CIFAR 10

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have tried using MSE on Resnet50 for the CIFAR10, no matter how I change the output layer like dense(1, relu)/dense(1, sigmoid). The model failed to converge in the training. What is the correct way to change the parameter to allow the use of MSE on CIFR-10 ?

Comment: The CIFAR-10 dataset is a classification problem, whereas the mean squared error loss is a loss used for regression problems. It therefore doesn't make sense to use this loss for such a problem and it is therefore not unexpected that your model won't converge using this loss. Is there a specific reason you want to use the MSE loss for this dataset?

Comment: I want to make a comparison between loss function in classification task. I know that  MSE/MAS are loss functions but they can be used in the classification task. For example, MAE will be more robust on CIFAR100 than CE. So, I wanna ask how to use MSE/MAE on the classifications.

Comment: Just using the MSE as the loss function is as simply as just changing it in the `fit` method (assuming you are using keras/tensorflow. If you just want to compare different loss functions I think seeing that using MSE does not allow the model to converge already shows you how it performs compared to a more appropriate loss function (e.g. cross entropy loss).

Comment: But the situation that the model is not converging is not reasonable. I observe that lots of research paper used MAE/MSE for the CIFAR dataset. For example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.09482.pdf, table 2. The performance with CIFAR using MAE/MSE should work. But I dont really understand how they converge in training. Is there any special method for this ?